# Registration with regasm error

Tags: regasm

I am asked to register a dll by using regasm but new to it. Here is my questions:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.030319\regasm XXX.dll/codebase. It says error RA0000: Unable to locate input assembly 'xxx.dll/codebase' or one of its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Put a space after the dll, before /codebase.

```
..\regasm xxx.dll /codebase
```